# pandas drop function gives more rows

Tags: python, pandas

Original df has 100000 rows and I have a index list to be dropped from the df here.

This list has 27346 rows so the df is supposed to have (100000-27346) rows after doing index drop function, but it comes out with 72852 rows and it's more than expected.

```
len(df) = 100000
len(index_list) = 27346
df_new = df.drop(index_list)
len(df_new) = 72852
len(df) - len(index_list) = 72654
```

Any advice will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: maybe some index are duplicated? is the size of `set(index_list)` also 27346?

Comment: @Joe that would delete more rows, which would result in a smaller size not larger

Comment: You have to provide a [MCVE], where this issue can be replicated on a smaller subset of the dataset. Otherwise, maybe the result is actually correct...

Comment: @AlexandreNixon The problem is that `72654` are expected, but there are `72852`. So my guess is that are wanted less

Comment: @Joe yes, so if there where duplicated indices, more rows would be dropped, so the result would be smaller than `72654`, not larger. The opposite is occurring.

Comment: thanks everyone. ive already done set(df.drop(index_list)&df.loc(index_list)) to make sure any duplicate has happened but they have no duplicates between themselves so i dont reallly know what to do

Comment: @Joe You're wight I was understanding the set of indices in the df instead of those from the list. Sry about that. Seems like the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is flawed. Consider the case where `index_list = [1] * 237346` and the index `1` belongs in your input dataframe. Then you have:

```
len(df) - len(index_list)  # 72654
len(df)                    # 100000
len(df_new)                # 99999
```

Make sure your `index_list` is unique via (for example) `index_list = list(set(index_list))` and, of course, for your tests to line up you should ensure the indices actually exist in your dataframe as *unique* identifiers.